# Makefile recipe that works when target file base name is different from prerequisite file?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile in which a couple of targets need to be made the same way, but one of the targets is a file whose basename is different from its prerequisite. Here is a minimal example:

```
ABOUT.html: README.md
help.html: help.md

%.html: %.md
    pandoc --standalone --quiet -f gfm -H $(github-css) -o tmp.html $<
    inliner -n < tmp.html > $@
    rm -f tmp.html
```

With this Makefile, `help.html` gets made but `ABOUT.html` is never made. The reason, I presume, is because the base file name for `%.html` and `%.md` don't match up in the case of `ABOUT.html` because that target depends on `README.md`.

Is there a way to make this work without having to make a separate recipe for `ABOUT.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create `ABOUT.md` symlink, so that your pattern rule works, by adding the following rule:

```
ABOUT.md : README.md
    ln -s ${<F} ${@F}
```

---

You may like to avoid using the same temporary file in the recipe because that breaks in parallel builds. A better way is to use a unique temporary file for the target based on the target name:

```
%.html: %.md
    pandoc --standalone --quiet -f gfm -H $(github-css) -o $@~ $<
    inliner -n < $@~ > $@
    rm -f $@~
```

Comment: This totally works. Thank you for the tip about the temporary file too.

Comment: @mhucka You can probably get rid of the temporary file completely: `pandoc --standalone --quiet -f gfm -H $(github-css) $< | inliner -n > $@`.